# iFrame contents not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm new to this and I don't know how I screwed up the code. The "verify" button isn't being displayed.

**Concept image:**
[Verify dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1VCT.png)

**HTML:**

```
<div style="text-align: center;">     
        <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 434px; height: 243px; position: relative;" id="i_div">
        <iframe name="i_frame" src="http://example.com/560087" 
            style="border: 0pt none ; left: -11px; top: -65px; position: absolute; 
            width: 1173px; height: 588px;" scrolling="no">
        </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p> </p>
</footer>
```

Comment: add full code. not just those two line.

Comment: @Andam, I have added the full code. Thank you so much.